# Is it possible to skip all gradle task with certain type?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle test task that is setup as following -

```
sourceSets {
    contractTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    contractTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    contractTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

task contractTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs contract tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.contractTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.contractTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I was hoping that after executing a command like this - 
`./gradlew build -x test` above task (along with all testing tasks - unit, integration etc.) will get skipped. I am able to skip this task by explicitly mentioning `-x contractTest` in the gradlew command. Is there any way to skip all tasks that are associated with some type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-x` (for `--exclude-task`) flag allows you to exclude tasks by **name**, not by **type** (see [Command-Line interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line)).

But there is a better approach to skip all "testing" task : just use the dedicated `check` lifecycle task:

- make `check` task depend on all your custom testing task,

  `check.dependsOn contractTest`
- exclude `check` when building:

  `./gradlew build -x check`

`check` task is described here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks